# Video and Telemetrics not in sync

Tags: video, sync

I've recorded a video with Raspberry Pis [Camera Module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module/).
On top of that I've recorded GPS data including the GPS Timestamp and [made my own data file](https://gopro.com/support/articles/i-want-to-make-my-own-data-file-how-can-i-make-it-work-with-dashware).

Using [Dashware](http://www.dashware.net/) I've tried to get the video and telemetrics [in sync](https://gopro.com/support/articles/how-do-i-synchronize-the-video-and-data-so-the-right-values-are-shown-at-the-right-time).

Unfortunately it just wont't work as the datafile runs much faster than the video file. In the end there is ~1,5 hours that are not covered with data.

My question is:
What is best practice in order to get the video and data in sync?

Comment: Where did the time information come from for the data file? If you have actual time stamps, do they agree with the duration of the video?

Comment: The time information hence the timestamps came from a gps module. So its supposed to be accurate. Yes they do agree with the duration of the video.
I guess it might be the speed of processing the data rows. The timestamps have different lags inbetween them. Probably dashware runs lets say one row per second although the real time difference between every row is higher than that. As I dont know how Dashware processes the rows, its hard to find a fix for that. Maybe though there is a function that dashware recognizes the timestamp and calculates the delay before the next row gets processed.